# Grep command not working within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file testtns.txt which has numbers like below :

```
123  
456
```

I am then passing the input of the file folder path like "/var/www/batchfiles/files/test.csv" . The test.csv has following records :

```
1,123,On its way to warehouse,20230131  
2,456,On its way to warehouse,20230201  
3,777,Pickedup,20230201  
4,888,Pickedup,20230202
```

I have created the script printgrep.bash to read the numbers from the file testtns.txt and then grep the csv files in folder "/var/www/batchfiles/files/". I am running the script using command `.\printgrep.bash /var/www/batchfiles/files/*` and excepting the output to be in output.txt as follows :

```
1,123,On its way to warehouse,20230131  
2,456,On its way to warehouse,20230201
```

However when I run the above command, output.txt is empty and doesnt have any results. However if I run the grep command as it is, it does return results as excepted.

Can someone let me know why the grep command not working in the below script printgrep.bash :

```
#!/bin/bash  
cat testtns.txt | while read line  
do  
grep -i "^ $line" $1 >> output.txt  
done
```

Tried even below grep command but still didnt work :

```
#!/bin/bash  
cat testtns.txt | while read line  
do  
grep -i "$line" $1 >> output.txt  
done
```

Comment: If your files have been anywhere near MSWindows, check for `\r\n` line endings with `cat -vet file | head -5` . If you see `^M$` at the end of each line, then `dos2unix file` will clean them up. BUT why aren't you using the `grep` feature that reads a search list from a file? `grep -f searchList.txt file1.txt file2.txt ... fileN.txt  (as many as you want)` . Good luck.

Comment: `grep -i "^ $line"` will not work because it looks for lines that start with a space, immediately followed by the string/pattern in `$line`. Since the actual lines start with another number, then a comma, *then* the string in `$line`, it'll never match. Also, are there other files in /var/www/batchfiles/files/? The way you seem to be doing it, it'll only search the first one in that directory. BTW, I tried to clean up the formatting of your question, please check and correct if I messed anything up.

Comment: @shellter You are correct. My input file was from MSWIndows and hence had \r\n endings. Your suggestions helped and fix the issue. I got it working. Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Could just be a typo here, but `.\printgrep.bash` shoudl be `./printgrep.bash`.  Using `\\` will try to backslash the "p".